# nnCron. Run php-script in console without open it

Tags: php, command-line, console, nncron

My OS is Windows.

I installed 'nnCron' and wrote the following line in 'nncron.tab':

```
33 14 * * 2 *  E:\server\php\php.exe "E:\server\www\1.php"
```

When 14:33 comes and executing of '1.php' starts, I see console window. If the script is executed for a long time, I see it for a few seconds. What should I write in 'nncron.tab' additionally to make this window not appear? Something like daemon. Or, maybe, there is alternative way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use the Windows task scheduler? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler

Comment: @Josep, at first, I have 0x80070005 err when try to create task. Secondly, I have different Windows version from version, which installed in company, which will run this script later. Thirdly, I want to use exactly this program, if the goal of concealing window is achievable.

Answer (score 0):

```
#( Task_135911112015
Time: 33 14 * * 2 *
Action:
    SWHide
    START-APP: E:\server\php\php.exe "E:\server\www\1.php"
)#
```